# React link imported variable to state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an external module file `Task.ts` which has the following:

```
const taskList: Task[] = [];

Class Task {
    ...
}

export { Task, taskList }
```

And `taskList` is a list of `Task` objects that is modified by the `Task` class.

Then I have my main `app.tsx` file. And I'm importing the list and the class like so:

`import { Task, taskList } from "./Task"`

So I'm just wondering if there is a way to link `taskList` to a react state so that changes to `taskList` through the `Task` object will trigger a re-render. I've tried `useEffect` and putting `taskList` in the dependency array, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: If your app component depends on the taskList, it should be a state of your app component, instead of the Task component

Answer (score 0):

If `taskList` can be updated from outside the App component or its childrens then you have to handle an event somehow and trigger useEffect to run to get the updated `taskList` array then update the state that holds `taskList`.
 I can think of emit a socket event each time you update `taskList` and listen for it from `useEffect` in App this will make the component rerender with the updated data when `taskList` is updated.

otherwise you can update your state each time you update `taskList`, make each method of `Task` not only do its work but also returning `taskList` so you can easely call it and update the state after each change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useState` and here is a simple example:

The function `updateList` is responsible for modifying the `tasks` state variable when a new task is added. It takes the `newTaskContent` as a parameter, creates a new `Task` object with the provided content, and then updates the `tasks` state variable by adding the new task to the existing list (`taskList`) using the spread operator (...). 
the `tasks` will automatically re-render when the state variable `tasks` is updated using the `setTasks` function.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Task, taskList } from './Task';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(taskList);
  const [taskContent, setTaskContent] = useState('');

  // Function to modify the taskList and trigger re-render
  const updateList = (newTaskContent) => {
    const task = {
      isDone: false,
      content: newTaskContent,
    }
    const newTask = new Task(task);
    const updatedTaskList = [...tasks, newTask];

    // Update the state variable to trigger re-render
    setTasks(updatedTaskList);
    setTaskContent(''); // Clear input field after adding task
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {tasks.map((task, idx) => (
        <div key={idx + 1}>{task.content}</div>
      ))}

      <input
        type="text"
        value={taskContent}
        onChange={(e) => setTaskContent(e.target.value)}
      />

      <button onClick={() => updateList(taskContent)}>Add Task</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is a simplify using vanilla JavaScript, and in addition to the example below, `useState` takes care of re-rendering the objects when it changes.

```js
// Array of objects 
var tasks = [
  {
     isDone: true, 
     content: "Learn JavaScript"
   }
];

// The class Task
class Task {
  constructor(content, isDone=false) {
    this.isDone = isDone;
    this.content = content;
  }
}

// Add a new task function
const addTask = (newTaskContent) => {
  // Create a new Task object
  const newTask = new Task(newTaskContent);  
  // Update the array using spread operator
  tasks = [...tasks, newTask];
  console.log(tasks);
};

// Call addTask function and pass the content
addTask("Learn C++");
```

More about `useState` and re-rendering:

[ReactJS | How does React associate Hook calls with components?](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components)
 
[Medium | React Hooks - Understanding Component Re-renders](https://medium.com/@guptagaruda/react-hooks-understanding-component-re-renders-9708ddee9928)